# How do I turn a string number into an int array of the individual digits

Tags: c++, string

I have 20 digit strings ex: 12345678912345678912.
I want to turn this into an array of ints [1,2,3...2]
How would I do that? 
(I kept getting errors with sstream, atoi/stoi)

Comment: Do you really need to convert it? In a way, it's already an array of integers. For most purposes you could just offset its elements by `-'0'`.

Comment: Could you please post what you have tried so far?

Comment: Sure, will edit soon^

Answer (score 3):

Create a new array, and convert each number character to number. Just subtract `'0'` from the number character and you will get the number.

The number character - `'0'` = the ASCII value of that character - the ASCII value of `'0'` = the number.

```cpp
std::vector<int> digits;
for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)
    digits.push_back(s[i] - '0');
```

Comment: Hi @HK boy - your code looks fine to me, though the poster wished to convert the string into an array of integers.

Answer (score 3):

Using [ASCII](https://ascii.cl/) is way to here.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cstring>
    using namespace std;

    int main() {
        string s;
        cin>>s;
        int len = s.length();
        int arr[len];

        for( int it=0; it<len; it++ ){
            // using ascii value
            arr[it] = s[it] - '0';
        }

        for(int it=0; it<len; it++){
            cout<<arr[it]<<" ";
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    // convert char to int
    std::string str = "12345678912345678912";
    int digits[str.size()];
    for (size_t i=0; i<str.size(); i++) {
        digits[i] = str[i] - '0';
    }


    // print out the string
    std::cout << str << std::endl;

    // print out the digits
    for (size_t i=0; i<str.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << digits[i];    
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn to work with C++ standard `string` and character strings. Then learn to use standard function to convert character to integer. Following are some useful references:

- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/
  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/
  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncpy/

Above mentioned solutions are correct. Here is another way to solve your problem.

```
int main()
{
  string input = "123456789";
  int sum = 0;
  const char * icstring = input.c_str(); // input character string
  for(int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++)
  {    
    char scstring[2]; // single character string
    // Copy first digit to scstring
    strncpy_s(scstring, icstring, 1); 
    // Convert scstring to integer using C library function 'atoi'
    int digit = atoi(scstring); // cout << "i = " << endl;    
    sum += digit;
    icstring++; // process next character
  }
  cout << "Sum of integers : " << sum << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi @vcp - your code may be correct, though the poster wished to convert the string into an array of integers.